# Facebook stream actor_id field

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

Good day, everyone!

I'm trying to get user's newsfeed via fql-query to stream. The query is as follows :

```
 NSString *query = @"SELECT post_id, actor_id, type,  message, created_time, attachment  FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'nf'";
```

Server answer's JSON representation has an "actor_id" field with id of news feeder. Now, i need to get name of user or group or page and their avatar. To do this, i must make a query to 3 different tables of users, groups or pages.

The question is , how to detect, if the actor id is a group, user or page id?
Every answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I used a multiquery like this:
1: SELECT * FROM Stream
2: SELECT * FROM users WHERE ActorId IN (first query with only field actorId)
3 : SELECT * FROM page WHERE ActorId IN (first query with only field actorId)
And then I match them myself in my own code, note that you CAN NOT post on behalf of a group. So an actorid can only be a page or a user. Nothing else

Comment: Yep, my solution is absolutely like yours. Thanks for response